# Sqlite3 warns about an "Incompatible pointer types"

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite

I'm fairly new to sqlite (3 hours)

What i want to do here is to get a database row into a custom object (the objects has the same nr. of propertys as the nr. of columns in the table...so it shouldn't be a problem there)

So this is my code :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
#import "Headers.h"
@interface DataDb : NSObject{
sqlite3 *database;
}

+(DataDb*)database;
+(Singleton*)getSgForIndex:(int)index;

@end





#import "DataDb.h"

@implementation DataDb

static DataDb *database;


+(DataDb*)database
{
    if(database==nil){
        database=[[DataDb alloc]init];
    }
    return database;
}


-(id)init{
    if(self=[super init]){
        NSString *sqliteDb =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

        if(sqlite3_open([sqliteDb UTF8String], &database) !=SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
            return nil;
        }

    }
    return self;
}


+(Singleton*)getSgForIndex:(int)index{

    Singleton *returnSingleton =[[[Singleton alloc]init]autorelease];
    NSString *query =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Quiz WHERE Q_Id=%i",index];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog (@"Works!");
        /*
        ...code...
        */

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Failed!!");
    }


    return returnSingleton;
}


-(void)dealloc{
    sqlite3_close(database);
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

..and the compiler has the following problem at the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` function:

Incompatible pointer types passing 'DataDb *' to parameter of type 'sqlite3 *' (aka 'struct sqlite3 *')

To be fair...the code is a modified version of a sample code i found but it worked for the guy in question and i don't understand why doesn't it work for me

Comment: show me which tutorial you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've declare getSgForIndex as a class method not an instance, the reference to database ends up being the `static DataDb *database` and not the `sqlite3 *database` that you want. You'll have to make getSgForIndex be an instance method, not a class method. (and you might want to not call them both database to aid in reducing confusion)